# Flutter animated Row overflow inside box smaller than a child

Tags: flutter, layout, overflow

There is a box in which I need to animate a child consisting of a Row in which there are two Text. (In short - running line). Both texts in the result must be on the same line.

The child I want to animate is wider than the parent anyway and when animating, an overflow error pops up.

Overflow error

[image]

How can this be avoided?

This is code:

```
  final Widget content = SizedBox(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Text('TEXT 1'),
        Text('TEXT 2')
      ],
    ),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
      Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: widget.parentWidth,
        height: UI_SIZE,
        child: ClipPath(
          clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
          child: SlideTransition(
            position: _offsetAnimation,
            child: content,
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it with `OverflowBox`.

```
final Widget content = OverflowBox(
  maxWidth: double.infinity,
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      Text('TEXT 1'),
      Text('TEXT 2')
    ],
  ),
);
```

Maybe someone will help this solution

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
final Widget content = SizedBox(
child: Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  children: [
   Expanded(child: Text('TEXT 1'),),
   Expanded(child: Text('TEXT 2'),),
  ],
),
);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't specify that I need a single line as a result.
I have updated the post with this requirement.
This solution did not help, because it makes a line break.

Comment: i didn't get your point.